# Pythonic way to manage imports of objects from another directory

Tags: python, import, python-module, python-3.7

**There are a number of similar SO questions but I believe my concern is different. Please read the problem completely.**

When I run `tree` command in my project directory named `Project`, it gives me the following

```
.
├── app1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── hello.py
└── app2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── utils.py
```

Contents of `hello.py`

```
from math import factorial

from app2.utils import hello

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()
    print(factorial(5))
```

contents of `utils.py`

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello()
```

Running `python app2/utils.py` from `Project` directory gives me the following:

```
hello
```

However, running `python app1/hello.py` from the same `Project` directory results in an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app1/hello.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app2.utils import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app2'
```

After reading a number of SO answers, I found a workaround this problem. The answer suggest adding below lines at the top of `hello.py`

```
import sys

sys.path.append(".")
```

The suggested approach does solve my problem but the same does not seem pythonic to me (adding same set of lines in each file).

**Are there any better ways to achieve the same?**

Thanks.

Comment: Your imports should work correctly if you set your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. Try running: `PYTHONPATH=. python app1/hello.py` (assuming you're on linux) - Note: I use virtualenv to solve this problem instead.

Comment: @byxor, I had to manually add `Projects` directory to PYTHONPATH, is this the recommeded way while starting every new project?

Comment: Not really. Most people use `virtualenv` or the newer tool, `pipenv`. It will automatically set the PYTHONPATH to the desired root of your project (so you don't have to). --- There are many good tutorials that explain what those tools are for.